# Passing values from controller to view

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs

Controller

```
public ActionResult Booklist(string bookid) {
   return View();
}
```

View

```
// other codes 
url: 'Index/Booklist',
method: 'POST',
success: function (a) {
   var windows = window.open('Index/Booklist');
}
```

But it seem to invoke `dispose();` twice..the reason being the first time it calls `return View();` and the second `var windows = window.open('Admin/GenerateQRCode');`
    I need to pass data from controller to javascript in sencha and also pass them to the View..is this possible?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+data+from+controller+to+view+asp

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Passing values from controller to view. But when doing so this code is being invoked twice, as I can see that it has called my `dispose();` method. I'm trying to see what is the issue.  @MarkC.

Comment: In the snippet you provided there are no values being passed to the view from the controller. It's just returning the Booklist view.

Comment: I am thinking of a solution for that too... @MarkC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Booklist([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,string bookid) 
{
//result should be your data.
var result=0;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}



 // other codes 
    url: 'Index/Booklist',
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
          'bookid': bookid
         },
    success: function (result) {

    }
```

Please try this.. Sorry earlier one is not working...

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Booklist", "Home")",
            data: {
                'bookid': bookid

            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {

            }


        });

public ActionResult Booklist( string bookid)
        {
            var result=1;
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is work for me...

Comment: it doesn't work! Booklist is underlined and states that inconsistent accessibility: DataSourceRequest is less accessible than Booklist @user3492367

Comment: What type of data you need to return to the view page? And you need to put url :"@Url.Action("ControllerName", "MethodName")",

Comment: For now I want to return bookid. In the later part  to change to an array of bookid @user3492367

Comment: What type of error you have got? Is this in controller level/ jquery level?

Comment: I received this error in the controller level..it doesn't seem to read DataSourceRequest too and it crashed the codes so I removed it after that..@user3492367

Comment: Sorry.. Use this one..public ActionResult Booklist( string bookid)
        {
            return Json(bookid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: It's ok! Anyways it is still working in the same way as my codes(calls dispose method twice). But I found the answer to it! It is to remove all the codes and leave `var windows = window.open('Index/Booklist');` to prevent dispose method from calling twice. Thanks alot for the help! :D @user3492367